# Llamado de funciones en C

Tags: c, ascii

He estado teniendo muchos problemas con las funciones, se para que sirven, pero no entiendo muy bien como llamarlas y como hacer que me devuelvan lo que necesito. Necesito crear un programa que me devuelva los primeros k números primos y ese valor mostrarlo en binario, ya tengo los programas con los que realizaría eso, pero he estado teniendo problemas en como llamar las funciones o como mostrar lo que me da la subrutina. Aquí les muestro lo que llevo.

Este es el programa que realice sin subrutinas o funciones y funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define k 30    //cantidad de numeros primos a buscar
#define MAX 128 // para 8 bits

int main (){

    int x, i,cont = 0;
    int state = 0;
    unsigned int binario = MAX;
    printf("Los primeros %d numeros primos son:\n\n", k);

    for(i = 2 ; cont < k ;i++){           //consigue los primeros k numeros primos
        state = 0;
        for(x = 2 ; x <= i ;x++){
        if(i % x == 0){
            state++;
        }

    }
        if(state == 1){
        printf("%3d = ",i);
        cont++;
        state = 0 ;

      for(binario = MAX; binario > 0; binario >>= 1){    //convierte a binario
        if (binario & i){
            printf("1");
        }
        else{
            printf("0");
        }
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    }
}
```

Acá seria lo mismo pero utilizando los programas como subrutinas
Donde hay /**/ es por que no se que poner exactamente ahi, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define K 11    //cantidad de numeros primos a buscar

int prime(/**/);
int contador (/**/);

int main(){ //aqui poner el llamado de las rutinas para poner el numero primo convertido a binairo.

}

int prime (/**/){   //consigue los primeros k numeros primos

    int x,cont = 0;
    int state = 0;

    for(i = 2 ; cont < K ;i++){
        state = 0;
        for(x = 2 ; x <= i ;x++){
        if(i % x == 0){
            state++;
        }

    }
        if(state == 1){
        printf("%d",i);
        cont++;
        state = 0 ;
        }
    }
}

int contador(/**/){     //un valor x lo convierte a binairo

    unsigned int contador = 128;
      for(contador; contador > 0; contador >>= 1){
        if (contador & x){
            printf("1");
        }
        else{
            printf("0");
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno pienso que debes de hacer un tutorial basico en C pero aca te dejo lo que debes entender.

- Los tipos basicos de datos en C son `int`, `double`, `float` y `char`. Esto significa que no nesesitas ninguna libreria para poder utilizarlos, son nativos del C y todas las clases y otros tipos de datos se basan en estas 4.
- Una variable es un tipo de dato que puedes almacenar para usar despues. Y vive segun el contexto en el que las asignes o declares.
- Una funcion(del paradigma de la programacion funcional) sirve para minimizar, reutilizar y mejorar el codigo en segmentos. En C tu tienes que llamar las funciones dentro de la funcion especial y reservada para el funcionamiento `main`.
- No se porque les llamas subrutinas a las funciones, eso lo dejo a tu decision, las funciones tienen una sintaxis basica que deben cumplir(digo basica porque vas a ver locuras si te adentras en lo avanzado) y se resumen en lo siguiente:

```
|---> tipo de dato que vas a devolver (float, char, int, void)
|           |--> Nombre de la funcion
|           |                |--> Parametros
|           |                |                   |--> cuerpo de la funcion   
int funcionQueFunciona(int parametro) {  return parametro;  }
```

- Existen [palabras](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/list-all-keywords-c-language) especiales que son del lenguaje y no puedes usarlas, deberias memorizarlas todas.
- La logica de programacion varia segun el programador, asi que hay multiples soluciones para los problemas, en tu caso los numeros primos.

Con todo esto explicado, vamos con tu problema...

- El contexto del codigo se define por las llaves `{}` algo que esta adentro no puede salir o entenderse en otro lado a no ser que utilizes alguna variable global(no recomendado) o una macro(que reemplaza un acronimo dentro del archivo). En tu caso tu utilizas `#define K` que es una macro, si nesesitas usar funciones debes usar parametros dentro de `main()`.
- Al igual que las funciones en matematica, el parametro o los parametros son los valores que va a usar la funcion para producir un resultado, en tu caso los numeros primos hasta K, pero ojo que solo los queremos imprimir.

```
#include "stdio.h"
// En C las librerias se hacen por cabeceras `algo.h` y fuentes `algo.cpp` en este caso `stdio.h` es una libreria de C que sirve para imprimir y recibir datos de una consola, ademas de otras cosas. Para mas info busca en google.
// Esto es un comentario de solo sirve para una linea
/* Y esta es otra forma de hacer comentarios, pero dura hasta que le pones esto -> */
// Es bueno que utilizes comentarios para describir los pasos en tu codigo

// Definimos la funcion numerosPrimosHasta() para que tenga sentido usarlo en main
void numerosPrimosHasta(int limite) {
    //Creamos una variable adentro de la funcion ya que solo vamos a usarla dentro de esta y sirve para calcular si el numero de divisores es mayor a 2, ya que un numero primo solo es divisible entre 1 y el mismo.
    int seDividio;
    //Para eso creamos dos bucles, yo utilizo for por preferencia pero tambien se puede con while
    for (int i = 2; i <= limite; i++) {
    // Aca empiezo desde 2 ya que empezar de 1 es redundante y lo mando a correr hasta la variable que defini en el parametro limite
        seDividio = 0;
        // Ya que esto se va a repetir tengo que resetear el valor de "seDividio" a 0 para cada iteracion(repeticion de bucle)
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        // Aca entramos a otro bucle que va a verificar cuantos divisores tiene el numero, empezando desde 2 hasta el numero que estamos iterando "i"
            if (i % j == 0) {
                // en este if verificamos una division con el operador % que significa "si el residuo de la division entre i y j es 0"
                seDividio++;
                // aumentamos en 1 si es que se pudo dividir entre i y j
            }
        }
        if (seDividio < 2) { printf("%d ", i); }
        // terminando de iterar j, ahora imprimimos el valor "i" que hemos estado verificandole sus divisores, y solo si la variable "seDividio" es menor a 2 signiica que fue solo divisible entre si mismo, ya que todos los numeros son divisibles entre 1. No lo he mandado a iterar ya que es obvio
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    numerosPrimosHasta(33);
    //llamamos la funcion dentro de main para que corra en el programa
    //El lenguaje C solo hace caso a main para funcionar, tiene prioridad ante las demas funciones..
    // Si lo quieres hacer formalito como querias... solo agregale una variable K
    int k = 100;
    numerosPrimosHasta(k);
    return 0;
    // main es una funcion principal y como tal debe devolver un valor(con return), en este caso le digo que es 0 que en cuestiones del compilador significa operacion completada sin errores.

}
```

Estoy utilizando `void` porque no voy a devolver ningun valor, por eso no uso `return` dentro de la funcion. 
No lo confundas con `NULL` que es una macro del C al igual que tu `#define K` y significa 0.
 Espero que con todo esto te haya quedado claro como utilizar funciones y parametros, yo te recomiendo que leas todo en ingles, que en español la informacion es poca y confusa.

Comment: dame unos minutos estoy revisando tu codigo

Comment: Si, gracias, es que si conozco su función, pero aun no estoy muy familiarizado al usarlas, apenas estoy empezando en programación, no llevo mas de 2 semanas y aunque logre realizar lo que necesitaba, intente hacerlo por funciones separadas, solo que no pude implementarlo de la manera adecuada, es por eso que recurrí ayuda para entender mejor como las podría implementar.

Comment: @user214757 he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, una pregunta, que significa o que función tiene el poner int argc y el char*??

Comment: @user214757 son parametros para capturar los argumentos de el Simbolo del sistema o la linea de comandos(depende del sistema operativo). Al usar un programa por la pantalla negra siempre tiene esta forma `notepad.exe algo.txt` pues alli hay 2 argumentos `argc` y 2 cadenas de caracteres `notepad.exe` y `algo.txt` que se capturan en `argv[]` es algo avanzado que ya aprenderas despues y no forma parte de este hilo. Por favor si mi respuesta soluciono tus dudas debes marcarla con el check verde ya que esta resuelta

Comment: Agradezco toda la ayuda, pero no se como marcar la pregunta como resuelta, no estoy muy familiarizado con la pagina.